how to search from firestore by flutter
want to ask how i can add a search from firestore  and display it  I am trying but it is not working with me
I tried to make methods and import but it's not working here is the method I used

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class SearchService {

   searchByName(String searchField) {     

     return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Names')         
              .where('name',isEqualTo: searchField.substring(0, 
                1).toUpperCase()).get();

   }
 }


"it is not working" is rather broad. Is there an error message? If not, can you show the value you use for searchField (or better yet: provide a hard-coded value in the question), and show a (screenshot of) a document you expect the query to return? --- There's a small edit link under the question allowing you to make such changes.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

The searchField.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() part only takes the first character of the search term and makes it uppercase. This may not give the expected search results if the name in the database is not just a single character or if the user inputs more than one character. You should use the full search term for better results.
Modified search method:
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class SearchService {
  Future<QuerySnapshot> searchByName(String searchField) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Names')
        .where('name', isEqualTo: searchField)
        .get();
  }
}

This method returns a list of documents based on a search term.
You can use a FutureBuilder to display the results of your search.
Here is the example to demonstrate how can you implement this:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class SearchPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchPageState createState() => _SearchPageState();
}

class _SearchPageState extends State<SearchPage> {
  final SearchService _searchService = SearchService();
  final TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();
  Future<QuerySnapshot>? _searchResults;

  void _performSearch() {
    setState(() {
      _searchResults = _searchService.searchByName(_searchController.text);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Search Names'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: _searchController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Enter name to search',
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _performSearch,
              child: Text('Search'),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: _searchResults == null
                  ? Center(child: Text('No results to display'))
                  : FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                      future: _searchResults,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                        }

                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
                        }

                        if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
                          return Center(child: Text('No results found'));
                        }

                        return ListView(
                          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) {
                            return ListTile(
                              title: Text(doc['name']),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


its not working in my project bro
